# Docker HaProxy exposed ports

Tags: docker, haproxy

Ran into an issue today while running `Docker` with `haproxy`. I cannot currently connect to my `haproxy` statistics page outside of the localhost. When I run the following command `curl localhost:1337`, I can see the `haproxy` statistics page.

When I try to access the page from the outside world, using the server's IP address I cannot.

Running `docker ps` shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e3fea8e39543        demo-haproxy        "haproxy -f /usr/loca"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp   my-running-haproxy2
```

My `Dockerfile` is relatively simple:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM haproxy:1.5
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
EXPOSE 1337
```

My `haproxy.cfg` file is also simple:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 10000
  timeout server 10000

listen stats *:1337
    stats enable
    stats uri /

frontend localnodes
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    balance roundrobin
    server web01 127.0.0.1:80 check

    option httpchk GET /
    http-check expect status 200
```

If anyone has any ideas on what I am doing wrong, please let me know. My expectation is that when I go to `my-server-ip-address:1337`, haProxy should show up.

**EDIT**

This is running on Microsoft's Azure platform. I have the 1337 endpoint open:

[image]

The command I used to start haproxy is as follows:

`docker run -d  -p  1337:1337 --name my-running-haproxy2 demo-haproxy`

Here is the result of my `sudo iptables-save`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Aug 25 20:57:09 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [95320:5717604]
:INPUT ACCEPT [50764:3044244]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18551:1256145]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [18552:1256185]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.1/32 -d 172.17.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:1337
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 25 20:57:09 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Aug 25 20:57:09 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [404037:61914084]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [405912:87310852]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 25 20:57:09 2015
```

Comment: Are there local `iptables` firewall rules that would prevent access to port 1337?

Comment: can you show your whole `docker run xxx` command?

Comment: @larsks, no I don't believe so. I have the public port exposed too. @user2915097 - I edited my note to include the `docker run` command. Thank you both

Comment: It works fine for me, are you running Windows or Linux?  If linux can you port the output of `sudo iptables-save` ?

Comment: Edited to include the `sudo iptables-save` information. Thank you, Rico.